# Blur view controller while presenting Uialertview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to make button which I press it will pop up `UIAlertView`. I would like to know if it's possible to blur everything around `UIAlertView` something like to put blur effect on that view controller. I've spent 2 hours finding solutions but nothing works as I expected. I wanna do the same thing on the picture

[image: UIAlertView with blur background]

Comment: Note that _UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS 8. (Note that UIAlertViewDelegate is also deprecated.) To create and manage alerts in iOS 8 and later, instead use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert._ what is the deployment target of your application ?

Comment: My deployment target is iOS 8.3 ... Oh yes you're right with UIalertView is deprecated I've meant UIAlertController

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need you use `UIBlurEffect` and `UIVisualEffectView` here is how your code should looks like:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{

    // Create blur effect
    UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];

    // Add effect to an effect view
    UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
    visualEffectView.frame = self.view.frame;


    self.alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle: @"Alert"
                                                           message: nil
                                                    preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


    [self.alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle: @"Cancel" style: UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        [visualEffectView removeFromSuperview];

    }]];

     [self.view addSubview:visualEffectView];

    [self presentViewController: self.alertController animated: true  completion: nil];

}
```

[UIVisualEffectView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIVisualEffectView/)

Result:

[image: UIVisualEffectView]

Comment: there a slight delay after the alert dismisses and the visualEffectView is removed from the superview. any idea how to encounter that?

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        // Create blur effect
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
        // Add effect to an effect view
    let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    visualEffectView.frame = view.frame

    alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        visualEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
    }))

    view.addSubview(visualEffectView)
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
}
```